# Insert event on Google calendar from Android API 15 or above

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need to add event to Google calendar programatically on few operations from my application.

I've tried [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) to insert events on calendar but it get inserted only on local calendar.  I also want events to get synced to the Google calendar.

I've also tried [Google calendar API for Android](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) but it says it requires `API 23 or later`.

I've tried Intent to add event in calendar, but opening an event requires user to click on OK button to add event in calendar, I want it without user's interaction.

So I need to add an event to Calendar programatically which get synced to Google calendar from Android API level 15 or above.

Comment: What have you done so far? If you've written any code yet (even pseudocode -- this helps to express what you're trying to do) share it. If it isn't working, include any relevant exceptions or output that would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: What I've tried is already working as I've said in my question. I am looking for way which meets my requirements. I've looked for four above methods but non of the them meets my requirements.